# Automation error when sharing Excel workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

An Excel workbook contains the following VBA macro in a Module, and calls it in several cells to generate a value.

When the workbook is shared (Review -> Share Workbook), it happens that a message box with "Automation error" is displayed when the workbook is opened, and the user cannot do anything except killing the Excel process from the task manager.

This happens with Excel 2013, no matter if the workbook is already opened by someone else or not.

The only solution I have in mind is to remove the VBA code from the workbook and store in an external XLAM add-in, like suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/904df485-d256-4e71-bce5-d3382d29127f/automation-error-on-shared-excel-2007-file-with-custom-functions?forum=excel). I don't want to do this for several reasons. By the way, I already tried this solution and a message saying that some links cannot be updated was displayed every time the workbook was opened.

Do you know if there is a way to avoid this "Automation error" message? Maybe it is related to the macro name, some references in the VBA project, or anything else?

```
Public Function OutFileName(OutType As String, OutNum As String) As String
 ' This function generates a filename from a file type and number

    Dim TempStr As String
    Dim i As Integer

    TempStr = LCase(Left(OutType, 1)) & OutNum

    ' If number begins with &, we directly go to the end of the macro
    If Left(OutNum, 1) = "&" Then
        GoTo EndOfMacro
    End If

    ' If it ends with a point and a digit, add a zero before the digit
    If Mid(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - 1, 1) = "." Or Mid(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - 1, 1) = "-" Then
        TempStr = Left(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - 1) & "0" & Right(TempStr, 1)
    End If


    ' Replace "." and "-" by underscore after "-"
        For i = Len(TempStr) To 1 Step -1
         If Mid(TempStr, i, 1) = "." Then
            TempStr = Left(TempStr, i - 1) & "_" & Right(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - i)
        End If
        If Mid(TempStr, i, 1) = "-" Then
            TempStr = Left(TempStr, i - 1) & "_" & Right(TempStr, Len(TempStr) - i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Delete other points and "-"
    TempStr = Replace(TempStr, ".", "")
    TempStr = Replace(TempStr, "-", "")

EndOfMacro:
    OutFileName = TempStr
End Function
```

Comment: Hm.. AFAIK you can't share a workbook that contains macros

Comment: You can - you just can't edit them once it's shared.